# Blowfish objective-c implementation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, blowfish

What objective-c implementation of Blowfish would you advice to use? (Or may be I just missed some standard implementations available?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Keep in mind that Objective-C is a superset of C, and so you don't need a specific Objective-C implementation. Blowfish written in C (like at [this page](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html), the first result of [googling "C blowfish implementation"](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c+blowfish+implementation)) will do you just fine.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. By the time you're dealing with crypto, you're dealing with bytes, which is really below the level of Objective-C (using NSData as a wrapper notwithstanding).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Thats what I actually thought, but just needed to see someone else opinion

Comment: I note that the security framework mentioned below now supports Blowfish. Haven't tried it myself but seems like it might be a better way to go as far as power consumption goes.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if you definitely wanted to go with blowfish, but the iPhone security framework supports the following out-of-the-box:

- kCCAlgorithmAES128  - Advanced Encryption Standard, 128-bit block
- kCCAlgorithmDES     - Data Encryption Standard
- kCCAlgorithm3DES    - Triple-DES, three key, EDE configuration
- kCCAlgorithmCAST    - CAST
- kCCAlgorithmRC4     - RC4 stream cipher

If you do decide to implement your own you may also need an arbitrary precision integer library, [libtommath](http://math.libtomcrypt.com/) will compile for the iPhone will little to no changes.